# How do i test for an entity relative to a player

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Im looking for a way to test if an entity is at a player's coordinates.

I've tried

```
/testfor @e[type=Shulker,name=Code] @a[r=1]
```

But it gives this

```
Data tag parsing failed: Invalid tag encountered, expected '{' as first char.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `/execute` to have the command executed from the player rather than the command block:

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ /testfor @e[type=Shulker,name=Code,r=1]
```